# "to put smth to the test" vs. "to put smth to a test"

Tags: phrase-meaning, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

What is the difference in the meaning between the two phrases: "to put smth to the test" and "to put smth to a test"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Put [x] *to the test*" is an idiomatic way of saying that you are submitting something to a process of testing. Even though "the test" uses the definite article, it refers to the process rather than a specific test, so that may involve one or more tests.

Your second option with the indefinite article is not as idiomatic. We would normally say that we put something *through* a test.

> We put our theory *to the test*.
>
> We put the car *through a test*.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put%20to%20the%20test%2C%20put%20to%20a%20test&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20to%20the%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20to%20a%20test%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cput%20to%20the%20test%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20to%20a%20test%3B%2Cc1) shows that "put to *the* test" is used far more than "a test". Interestingly, the few examples I looked up where "a test" is used were *past tense*, for example "it was put to a test".

Answer (score 0):

To me as a native speaker, to **put something to a test** implies that you are simply going to do a single thing as your test. For example, to put a car to a test you might check that the engine works and can move the car.

To **put something to the test** implies that you are going to do a longer, more extensive test. For example, you might drive it fast on the highway, take it on some bumpy roads, see how it handles sharp turns, how it deals with heavy loads under braking, etc.

*However*, I very rarely hear "put something to *a* test" used in everyday speech. Normally we would just say that we will **test** something, or **check** something.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say "I put [something] to **a** test". It just isn't idiomatic.

Comment: @Astralbee Agreed, though apparently it is a phrase in use in some places. Hence my cautious note.